# Slanted text in SVG

Tags: svg

In SVG is it possible to slant text to specified angle? This is of course different from rotate or putting on a path etc. One of things I want to do is to have a parallelogram with embedded text, with text tilted to the angle of the parallelogram. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You need to use the `transform` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="100">

  <text font-size="50" transform="translate(20,50) skewX(20)">Skewed text</text>

</svg>
```

Note that the transform applies to the text position (`x` and `y` attributes) as well. That's why I have used a translate to set the text position instead.